# How to solve a linear forward-looking equation $x_t = \beta E_t[x_{t+1}] + k$ where $\lim_{t \to \infty} x_t = 0$ and $0<\beta < 1$?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

How does one solve a linear forward-looking equation $x_t = \beta E_t[x_{t+1}] + k$ where $\lim_{t \to \infty} x_t = 0$ and constant $k,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, $0<\beta <1$?

Answer (score 1):

(I suspect that $E_t[x_{t+1}] = E(x_{t+1}\mid I_t)$, where $I_t$ is the Information Set, i.e. $E_t[x_{t+1}]$ is translated as "the expected value of random variable $x_{t+1}$ conditional on Information available at time $t$").

@FooBar answer implemented the "standard solution algorithm", arrived at a constant solution, and remarked that such a solution violates the limiting condition.
Strictly speaking, a constant solution would satisfy the limiting solution also, if it was equal to zero (which in our case implies $k=0$): If indeed we had as solution

$$x_t = \frac k{1-\beta}$$
then

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} x_t = \lim_{t \to \infty}\frac k{1-\beta} = \frac k{1-\beta} \neq 0$$

except if $k=0$. But this is trivial (or at least, uninteresting).

So I ask, **if $k\neq 0$, what would it take to obtain a solution**? The law of evolution must hold also at the limit so

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} x_t = \lim_{t \to \infty}\Big[\beta E_t[x_{t+1}] + k\Big]=0$$

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{t \to \infty}E_t[x_{t+1}] = -\frac k{\beta} \tag{1}$$

In words, as the random variable tends to zero, its expected value conditional on information available in the previous period, must equal a non-zero *constant*, while the variable itself tends to zero. Consider some cases, to see whether and when such a thing can happen:

**A)** If $x_t$ was *totally unobservable*, (not observed directly, and not amenable to indirect estimation though other variables)? In such a case, the information set would not contain any information on $x_t$, meaning that the conditional expected value would equal the unconditional one. So we would have,

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}E_t[x_{t+1}] = \lim_{t \to \infty}E[x_{t+1}] \tag{2}$$

This is economics, meaning that the properties of the mathematical entities should take into account what do they represent in the real world. So it would be meaningless *not* to assume that $x_{t+1}$ is *not* bounded (more over, this would mean that the $x$ random variable goes to infinity in finite time and then "comes back" to tend to zero in infinite time -and for those who may think "hyperinflation", hyperinflation is a *very very* small number compared to infinity). If it is bounded then the Dominated/Bounded Convergence theorem holds and we have that

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}E\left(x_{t+1}\right) =E\left(\lim_{t \to \infty}x_{t+1}\right) =0 \neq -\frac k{\beta} \tag{3}$$

So this is not a case in which we can obtain the required relation $(1)$.

**B)** The limiting condition is part of the information sets for finite $t$. Then immediately

$$E\left(\lim_{t \to \infty}x_{t+1}\mid I_t\right) =0$$

In words, at any point in time we know that the variable will tend eventually to zero. Can this be compatible with relation $(1)$? We could invoke again the boundedness of $x_t$, and a generalization of the Dominated Convergence Theorem, since here the (conditional probability) measure is also time-varying, and again obtain a zero expectation at the limit. But intuitively also, if we know that eventually the variable will tend to zero, at some point in time this must be reflected in $E_t$, most certainly at the limit. But then again, the required relation $(1)$ won't hold.

**C)** We do observe perfectly or imperfectly the value of the variable, but "we don't give proper notice": our Expectations are *not* Rational. In that case, the symbol $E_t$ *no longer represents the conditional expectations operator*, but it is just a generic symbol for the "anticipation at time $t$" (in Adaptive Learning literature this is usually symbolized by $E^*_t$) and *it acquires the value it needs to acquire for the limiting condition to hold*.  In other words, *given* the law of evolution *and* the limiting condition, we *conclude* that expectations must not obey the Rational Expectations Hypothesis, *not even at the limit*.

In such a case, a solution is obvious: *define* 
$$E^*_t(x_{t+1}) = -\frac {(1-c\beta^t)k}{\beta}$$

for some constant $c$, This expectations formation rule satisfies $(1)$, and  transforms the law of motion into

$$x_t = \beta \Big[-\frac {(1-c\beta^t)k}{\beta}\Big] + k = ck\beta^t$$

which in turn satisfies the limiting condition.

So we conclude that: **the specific equation, with the specific limiting condition, has a solution if expectations formation does not obey the Rational Expectations Hypothesis, but instead follows the above rule, or some other to the same limiting effect.**

Answer (score 0):

Since there is nothing random on the right-hand side, we know that the left-hand-side must be non-random either. Hence, we can drop the expectations operator

$$x_t = \beta x_{t+1} + k$$
$$x_{t+1} = \beta x_{t+2} + k$$
$$x_t = \beta (\beta x_{t+2} + k) + k$$
$$x_t = k + \beta k + \beta\beta x_{t+2} $$

Where we can now see where this equation is leading towards:

$$x_t = k\sum_{s=0}^\infty \beta^s + \lim_{T\to\infty} \beta^Tx_T$$

where I have used that the limiting term with $T\to\infty$ will converge to zero.

$$x_t = \frac{1}{1-\beta} k$$

Which yields a constant $x$. However, this violates $lim_{t\to\infty} x_t = 0$, as $x_t$ is a constant. To conclude, the given equation has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

As FooBar says, you can drop the expectation. Then derive the general $n$-th case for $x_{t}$ in terms of $x_{t+n}$

$$x_{t}=\beta^{n}x_{t+n}+k\sum_{i=0}^{n}\beta^{i}.$$

As $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\beta^{n} \rightarrow 0$ and (we are told) $x_{t+n} \rightarrow 0$.

So, using the above $$x_{t}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\beta^{n}x_{t+n}+k\sum_{i=0}^{n}\beta^{i}\right]=\frac{k}{1-\beta},$$
where we have used the fact that the geometric sum converges because $0<\beta<1$,
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\beta^{i}=\frac{1}{1-\beta}.$$

Comment: I ask here too: How does this solution satisfy the limiting condition if $k\neq 0$?